# Django: Match multiple LDAP groups to is_staff flag

Tags: django, python-2.7, ldap

I'm trying to match multiple LDAP groups to the is_staff flags in django settings.py

If I do LDAP or syntax:

```
"is_staff" : "(|(cn=example)(cn=otherexample))
```

it doesn't match either.  If I pull the LDAP syntax outside the quotes:

```
"is_staff" : (|("cn=example")("cn=otherexample"))
```

it syntax errors.
If I use python "Or":

```
"is_staff" : "cn=example" or "cn=otherexample"
```

It only matches the first one and if I use two "is_staff" flags:

```
"is_staff" : "cn=example"
"is_staff" : "cn=otherexample"
```

It only matches the second one.

Is there any way to match two different groups in django?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the way to match multiple groups is using a list format.

So

```
"is_staff" : ["cn=example", "cn=otherexample"],
```

Matches on both, and can have any number of entries.